# Airflow scheduler seems to spam API with login requests

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to load the following Airflow DAG (with schedule None)

```
with dag:
    conn = get_conn() # connection is calling API with login credentials
    op1 = PythonOperator(
        ...
    )

    op2 = PythonOperator(
        ...
    )
```

When I turn on airflow scheduler, the DAG doesn't get loaded with DAG Import Error:

> Exception: Could not login. Response: Too Many Requests

It seems that Airflow Scheduler executes the script repeatedly while calling the get_conn function, causing it to refuse my login attempt even when not running the DAG single time. Am I supposed to initialize connection in each PythonOperator separately? My plan was to initialize single connection and then pass it to each operator.

Comment: It's also possible the site is too busy handling other requests.  It doesn't necessarily mean they all came from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Dag is running the file is parsed every second. Files in the Dag Bag are also parsed at an interval, even when they aren’t running. When the file is parsed all top-level code is executed. Open and close the connection inside of the operators `execute()` method. This is an important concept of Airflow.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code